# I have been trying to load an angular2 component at runtime when a tab is clicked

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Basically I have so many components which are being loaded on the page load in different tabs as I have used their selectors at design time.

I want to load those components on demand (on Click of tabs).

Here  is the selector of a component which I want to load dynamically.
But it is loading the html as it is and not loading the component.

My code for loading a component is as below:

```
 ngOnInit()
  {   

$('#context1 .menu .items')
  .tab({
    cache: true,
    // faking API request
    apiSettings: {
      loadingDuration : 300,
      mockResponse    : function(settings) {
        var response = {
          first  : ' <div class="Context1">
          <div class="title">
        <div class="gap" style="height: 20%"></div>
        <label style="margin-left: 10px"> Charges</label>
        <div class="ui right floated tiny icon buttons primary" >
          <button class="tiny ui button">Create New Charges</button>
        </div>
          </div>
        <div class="content">
        <app-chargeslistview></app-chargeslistview>

       </div>
      </div>',
          second : 'AJAX Tab Two',
          third  : 'AJAX Tab Three'
        };

        return response[settings.urlData.tab];
      }
    },
    context : 'parent',
    auto    : true,
    path    : '/'
  });

}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is loading the html and not the component because Angular sanitizes DOM input like that.

What you'll need to do is use something like `componentFactoryResolver` to load an instance of a component dynamically.  The [Angular site has an article demonstrating something like this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html).  There are several other implementations of loading components dynamically, here are a few links on the subject:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-dynamic-component

http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/

https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/

The Angular runtime needs to be able to inject an instance of a component where the selector is, and just inserting HTML on a page at runtime bypasses the Angular runtime to handle that component.  If you could just insert stuff into the DOM and it run, then that would be a security vulnerability.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

**EDIT**

To do lazy loading routing with Semantic UI tab (I haven't tested this code, but it should be close) you should be able to do something like this:

```
//TEMPLATE
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/myFirstRoute']">First</a>
  <a class="item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/mySecondRoute']">Second</a>
  <a class="item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/myThirdRoute']">Third</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
  <router-oulet></router-oulet>
</div>
```

The `routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` evaluates the current route and adds the class `active` if the current route matches the routerlink.

Your routes could be lazy loaded, and if so, would look something like this:

```
//ROUTER

export const ROUTES: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'myFirstRoute',
    loadChildren: './routeOne/routeOne.module#RouteOneModule'
  },

  {
    path: 'mySecondRoute',
    loadChildren: './routeTwo/routeTwo.module#RouteTwoModule'
  },

  {
    path: 'myThirdRoute',
    loadChildren: './routeThree/routeThree.module#RouteThreeModule'
  }

];
```

The lazy loading would would make those modules be bundled separately in chunks, which would not be called from the server until the route is activated.  Then the chunk would be retrieved and loaded.

Hope that gets your pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Being new to Angular, I am not sure on which event should I call the Load Component() function to load it dynamically.  Is there any other way in which we can load the TAB data on click of tab.  I am sure, there must be some easier way.  In angular2, we can create lazy routes but for that we need a path . I tried setting a path  like :  /account/:id/TABNAME but it doesn't work.

Comment: Lazy loading routes is different than creating a component from an api response.  With lazy loading, you still need the component built and included in your application at compile time.  Are you wanting to include the component at compile time or build it from an api response at runtime?

Comment: As of of my requirement is to load the Tab data on click of tab. Each tab has a component associated with it. I am using Semantic-ui tab.   My Initial load of the application is taking too long as there are so many tabs and child tabs in my page.  I tried lazy loading but its not working either. So, i am trying to load the component dynamically but i don't know which event should I handle and how to load my component dyanamically.

Comment: My requirement is to include the different components to different semantic ui tabs at design dime. 

But when the tab is clicked the component should be loaded. But in my case the page loads all the components on its load that should not happen. 

Is there any way to dynamically(at runtime) include a component within a DIV?

How can I load those components on demand i.e. on click of tabs?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten back until now.  Yes, you can load the components on demand from the click of a tab.  You would have to setup your tab body with a `router-outlet` and the tabs themselves would route to different components/modules, which could be lazy.  I haven't used Semantic-ui personally, but I imagine the the code would be similar.  I accomplished this with plain bootstrap tabs.  Let me see if I can come up with an example for you.

Comment: Hi, Since I am already using router-outlet in main application, I created a named router-outlet(route2) to get this working and changed the link as below- 
 
  <a class="items" data-tab="Details" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['secondpage',{outlets: {'route2': ['detailpage']}}]"><i class="browser icon" ></i>Page Details</a> 


But when I am coming back on the tab second time I am getting below error:-

Comment: Cannot activate an already activated outlet ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:8085/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:5049:23)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:8085/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4337:20)

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with how the routing is setup.  There are a couple ways to solve this:  using named router outlets, or setting up  a new child module with it's own routing module and it's own router-outlet.  Can you provide a plunkr or something where I can see the full setup?